# Foreach launch a new powershell instance per loop with arguments?

Tags: powershell

I feel like I am so close I am just missing a syntax somewhere
I have a list of computers and I need to launch a new instance of powershell with the .ps1 script with the -computer argument

```
$computers = Get-COntent -Path c:\temp\patching\serversList.txt
Foreach ($computer in $computers){
start PowerShell “c:\temp\patching\install-patch.ps1” -computer $computer
}
```

Comment: Start-Process does not have a -ComputerName parameter.

Comment: the .ps1 needs the computer parameter, I am trying to pass that to the .ps1

Answer (score 1):

I think I fixed this, it is 3am so I think I am just sleep deprived trying to make it work
I needed to put the $computer argument inside the quotes

```
$computers = Get-Content -Path c:\temp\patching\serversList.txt
Foreach ($computer in $computers){
start PowerShell “C:\users\Administrator\Documents\install-windowsupdates.ps1 -computer $computer” 
}
```